# Darken/Dim background elements during loading animation - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-view, android-progressbar

In have a progress bar spinner that appears once the login button is clicked, I would like the elements behind the spinner to dim or darken while the spinner is visible on the screen. My layout file looks like this currently:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="apps.kusasa.biz.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        android:text="Login" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pics_logo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="77dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My button click method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loginBtn:
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // etc
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will be tough when your spinner is in the same layout as the elements that you would like to dim. I would move the spinner to a separately (parent) layout and then apply a background color with an alpha channel to the relativelayout.
For example #99000000

Comment: what type of layout would you use?

Comment: What about FrameLayout, then you can stack the elements

Comment: This route presented a huge number of problems, like the framelayout not filling the screen, the progressbar spinner no longer staying in the middle of the layout, and other things that require even more workaround.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was creating a custom dialog, which has only the progress bar (instead of a complete dialog as view):

```
class ProgressBarDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar_dialog)
        setCancelable(false)
        this.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

The view (`progress_bar_dialog.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's it. The dimmed background is given (by the `Dialog()` it extends) and by setting `setCancelable(false)` and overriding the `onBackPressed()` method the user can't dismiss it until waiting is over.
You just need to use it in your activity:

```
var mMyProgressBarDialog = ProgressBarDialog()
```

and then call `mMyProgressBarDialog.show()` when you need it to appear and `mMyProgressBarDialog.dismiss()` when you need it to disappear.

Hope this helps.